# Qt 5.3. QT_OPENGL_ES_2 always defined

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I want to use desktop OpenGL in my project. So i'm build Qt from source code with the following options:

```
configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop -no-angle
```

Then i adapt the code from that example: [OpenGL Window Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html)

Below is critical part:

```
OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow(QWindow *parent)
: QWindow(parent)
, m_context(0) {
    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface); 
}

...................

void OpenGLWindow::exposeEvent(QExposeEvent*) {
if (isExposed())
{
    if (!m_context) {
        m_context = new QOpenGLContext(this);
        m_context->setFormat(requestedFormat());
        m_context->create();

        m_context->makeCurrent(this);
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        initialize();
        m_context->doneCurrent();
    }       
    render();
} }
.......................
```

`initialize()` function of derived class uses some opengl methods, for example `glBindBuffer`. All works fine. But when I decide use use `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` with `glBindBuffer`, I got error `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. In debug session I can see that

```
inline void QOpenGLFunctions::glBindBuffer(GLenum target, GLuint buffer)
```

uses `QT_OPENGL_ES_2` branch. GLES does not support `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`.

I try to undefine `QT_OPENGL_ES_2` in project settings. Also i try define `QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2`. With no success.

Is there any ways undefine `QT_OPENGL_ES_2`?

Comment: What exact Qt version? 5.3 was quite full of OpenGL bugs fixed now in 5.4 (available). I also noticed many strange effects when we *rebuild* Qt over the previous build. No legitimate clean command helps. Not even jom confclean from qtbase. Not jom clean or distclean from Src. Not erasing all object files. They have so many different files generated that it makes sense to erase entire Src folder and start over or maybe try to erase all new files created during the build. I personally use Qt 5.3 static opengl es2 and that combination is fairly stable and usable.

Comment: It is 5.3.2 version. Windows 64 bit.

Comment: The same with Qt 5.12.0.